# AngularJS ng-repeat ng-show array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have array of array which needs to be able to be sorted and put in order

my problem is sorting objects by order and array that contains info which both is within the array, my approach was to use

```
<a ng-repeat="s in stops | orderBy:'+train_routes[0].stop_seq'"
ng-show="s.train_routes[0].route_id.indexOf('5') > -1">
```

because I have a lot of data and I don't want to organize it as it will become a much larger and crash

I know the problem is **[0]**, but I don't know any other way

I want it to show the object that has the array containing info

**This works**

```
    ng-show="s.train_routes[0].route_id.indexOf('6') > -1"
```

**this doesn't work**

```
    ng-show="s.train_routes[0].route_id.indexOf('5') > -1">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MbjKKtTbs3EgO6a4WCRL?p=preview

**EDITED**
Let's say the user wants to see specific train route, it must show all the stops on that train line, and show the other available trains linked to the requested by the user.

```
 ng-show="train_routes[0].IndexOf('requestedroute')"
```

will only show if the 0 index matches the requested route.

I will like it to show all the values in every index if the array contains the requested route

Comment: So you want to display the train routes?

Comment: @SeRu The json data cannot be change as I saw in your plnkr the value of the train_id was changed

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), so that you do not append useless elements in the DOM.

In the view:

```
<a ng-repeat="s in stops | filter: avoid5 | orderBy:'+train_routes[0].stop_seq'">
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.avoid5 = function(value, index, array){
   return value.train_routes[0].route_id.indexOf('5') > -1;
}
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough as this didn't solve my problem, thank you for the attempt